# Variables updated in fetch method don't retain in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

```
  const searchCacheFlightHotelsPackage = () => {
setValues({ ...values, loading: true });
let result = null;
getCacheFlightHotelsPackage() //returns a promise
    .then((data) => {
      if (data.list.length > 0) {
        result = paginate(data.list);
        hotelFlightPackageList = data.list;
      } else {
        console.log("sorry no packages found========");
      }
      console.log(hotelFlightPackageList);
      setValues({ ...values, loading: false });
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log("packages data error=======", e);
      setValues({ ...values, loading: false });
    });
```

I have variables outside this function like `let hotelFlightPackageList = [];` which updates in the method but once outside the method it's back to being an empty array. I have also tried using setValues which you can see an example of with the loading setting to false. I wish I could just update the global state in fetch but It gives a react hook error when doing that.

Comment: try out hotelFlightPackageList.push(data.list)

Comment: Didn't work but thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you create demo sandbox  or you can  add complete  component code  here to get exact answer

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can update the global state in fetch once you make the global state variable a const outside of the fetch! Working now!